# How do I redirect within a ViewResult or ActionResult function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Say I have:

```
public ViewResult List() 
{
    IEnumerable<IModel> myList = repository.GetMyList();
    if(1 == myList.Count())
    {
        RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = myList.Single().id });
    }

    return View(myList);
}
```

Inside this function, I check if there is only one item in the list, if there is I'd like to redirect straight to the controller that handles the list item, otherwise I want to display the List View.

How do I do this? Simply adding a `RedirectToAction` doesn't work - the call is hit but VS just steps over it and tries to return the View at the bottom.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to `return RedirectToAction` instead of just calling the RedirectToAction method.  Also, your method will need to return an `ActionResult` is a return type compatible with both `ViewResult` and `RedirectToRouteResult`.

```
public ActionResult List() 
{
    IEnumerable<IModel> myList = repository.GetMyList();
    if(1 == myList.Count())
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = myList.Single().id });
    }

    return View(myList);
}
```

Comment: That worked after changing the function return type to ActionResult, cheers!

Comment: Have been banging my head against the desk all morning trying to understand why RedirectToAction() wasn't working in my controller!  So simple!