# stymied by attack hampsters trying to unit test a method that returns an action result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

OK - So I started out like this,

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
   return View(service.GetProjects());
}
```

And here is my test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index_Will_Return_A_List_Of_Active_Projects()
{
   var view = controller.Index();
   Assert.AreEqual(view.ViewData.Model.GetType(), typeof(List<Project>));
}
```

All that is rocken with dokken but then I added login and if the user isn't authenticated I redirect them to the login page. Here is what the new method looks like.

```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
          return View(service.GetProjects());
      return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
   }
```

My problem is this - I can't figure out how to fix the unit test for the life of me. I can't return a ViewResult anymore so I can't check the .ViewData.Model property but I can't figure out how to redirect while still returning a viewresult. I have been trolling the site and I found this [How do I redirect within a ViewResult or ActionResult function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538469/how-do-i-redirect-within-a-viewresult-or-actionresult-function) but that doesn't really help.

If someone can tell me what to here that would rule - I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove that logic from your action and use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) instead.  Then your test doesn't change and you can create a seperate test that asserts the action is being decorated by the attribute.

```
[Authorize]
public ViewResult Index() 
{ 
    return View(service.GetProjects()); 
}
```

Comment: While Paul's answer does work I do like using the attribute in this case. thanks all!

Comment: No problem! Check out [this video on Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/DevDays/DevDays-2011-Netherlands/Devdays072) for some other good tips on "modern" MVC development using things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your test will have to add another step: assert that what's returned *is* a `ViewResult`. Then cast it if that assert succeeds, and continue on with the other assert.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index_Will_Return_A_List_Of_Active_Projects()
{
   var result = controller.Index();
   // this is called a guard assertion
   Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult)); 

   var view = (ViewResult)result;
   Assert.AreEqual(view.ViewData.Model.GetType(), typeof(List<Project>));
}
```

Comment: I think you mean typeof(ViewResult) and then cast it to a viewResult - not ViewData?

Comment: @Kenn You are, of course, correct. My mistake, I've edited the answer.