# MVC Redirect from a ViewResult where cannot change to ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, viewresult

I want to redirect from a `ViewResult`, so that I can display a specific product detail when the search result is `1` instead of the product list page.

Other pages said to change the `ViewResult` to an `ActionResult` and to use the `RedirectToAction`.  But my problem is that my controller inherits from a third party control and my search method is set to override the same third party control method, which is a `ViewResult`.

I am wondering if anyone has some suggestions on what I could do, if there is another way to redirect from a `ViewResult` or if there is another way to handle the override of the third party controls search method to be an `ActionResult`.

Comment: You need to post what you have, but ActionResult is compatible with both ViewResult and RedirectToRouteResult.  see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538469/how-do-i-redirect-within-a-viewresult-or-actionresult-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* just return a different View (without the redirect)

```
//in your action method
if( result.Count == 1 )
    return View( "Product", result[0] );
```

or call the other action method directly (if they are in the same controller)

```
if( result.Count == 1 )
    return YourActionDetails( result[0].Id /* params */ );
```

or, you could return a simple View that makes an automatic redirect client-side

```
// a "Redirect" view
@model Product
<html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=@Url.Action("Details", Model.Id)" />
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, the detail page returns an action result which is also set as override.  I may look into that last option.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the return type of the action than you could use routing to route requests with 1 to a different action.

Just define another route and make sure that it's added to `RouteCollection` *before* the default one.